# displaying the year of module without duplicates?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, rendering

I have a table with a module name and the information of the modules such as

:Computer science, 2001/02, level 3

:Computer Science 200/02, level 2

etc..
in a table called smod. I have done the sql behind it but I am trying to figure out the php that will allow me to display modules by year such as

**2001/02**

1. computer science
2. biology

**2002.02**

1. subject
2. subject

etc..

here is what I have so far

```
 <?php

$query2 ="SELECT mods.mid, ayr, mtitle, credits FROM stud, smod, mods WHERE      stud.sid = '".$_POST['stuNo']."' and stud.sid = smod.sid and smod.mid = mods.mid";

$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

echo "Enrolment and progress";
echo "<table width='150' border='1'>";

echo "<th> Module Selection</th>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$year = $row["ayr"];
if($year = $row["ayr"]){
} else {
    echo "<tr>".$row["ayr"]."</td>";
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row["mid"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["mtitle"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["credits"] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

?>

How could I display the information in that format? Thank you.

Comment: It might help if you gave the output, if any, you are getting now. Also, I think the title of the question could be clearer - perhaps something like 'use PHP to create an HTML table from a MSQL query, without duplicate rows'.

Comment: please don't post duplicates in the future

Comment: @Dagon how is this a duplicate?

Comment: you asked the same question twice, this was the first, but the 2nd has an answer so i made this the duplicate of the other.

Comment: @Dagon bloody hell I have absolutely no idea i did. lol Thanks!